# Prove $e^c>c^e$ if $c>0$ and $e \neq c$ using graph.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, exponential-function

I am on this question where it tells me to show $e^c>c^e$ if $c>0$ and $e \neq c$ using the graph of $\dfrac{(log(x))}{x}$.
[image]

Now it is obvious that the graph reaches a maximum at $x=e$ but how do i use this graph to show the above statement??
Any hints or advice to get me on the right track would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since the exponential function is increasing, it suffices to show that $\log(e^c) > \log(c^e)$ for $c > 0, c \not= e$. Can you do this?

Comment: so would I do this by rewritting it as $clog(e)>elog(c)$ which then forms $c>elog(c)$ and so we can rewrite it as $e>\dfrac{log(c)}{c}$ for which we know from the graph the greatest value of  $\dfrac{log(c)}{c}$ is when $c=e$ and from the question $c \neq e$ and inequality holds.

Comment: @Kimo: Might just be a typo in what you wrote but what you end up proving is actually $\frac{1}{e} > \frac{\log c}{c}$; otherwise you're right. It's not so important that $e$ is where the function attains its maximum; just that it's bounded by $1/e$ (away from $x = e$).

Comment: apologies it was a typo, thank you very much for your help

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: If this helped you, consider accepting and definitely up voting this answer.